# Cannot reinstall samba after deleting its config file from /etc/samba

Tags: software-installation, samba

I got mad about the broken config file for samba. I just deleted the `/etc/samba` folder. Now I want to reinstall samba but I cannot.

This is what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo vim /etc/samba/... # broke something in the config
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba
# realized that the config file in the `/etc/samba` is still there.
sudo rm -r /etc/samba
sudo apt-get install samba # getting error
```

I want to remove samba *(delete completely)* then install it like nothing happened before?

**How to do this?**

**[EDIT]**

```
dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**and**

- The first install was 54.2MB
- The uninstall was 11.5MB
- The second install was 11.5MB

Comment: After you purge it, if you then run `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`, does that make any difference?

Comment: Also, what is the output of `locate samba` and `service --status-all | grep samba` after running the purge command you ran and the one I gave?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well mostly your installation have install more dependent packages other than the samba package alone. So why your next install doesn't need the size of files that downloaded earlier.  So if you need to remove it completely like you asked then you need to uninstall it and remove the unwanted dependecies.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba samba-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After that If you find the config files in /etc/samba better rename it.

```
sudo mv  /etc/samba /etc/samba.old
```

Now you can install samba by issuing the command

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Thats it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove --purge samba samba-*` then install solved it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was fed up with those errors

Comment: This removed ubuntu-desktop as well as a few other things for me, weirdly.