# Cannot reinstall samba

Tags: networking, samba

I am running Ubuntu Server 18.04.

On 10 December 2018 samba stopped working. I know it was that day because I was backing up my Windows computer to Ubuntu Server every day with Macrium Reflect for months with out issue but ever since that day it has been reporting an error. I did not change or do anything that I am aware of to cause this problem. Ever since that day I have not been able access any samba shares on the Ubuntu Server computer from any other computer (linux or windows) nor can I access any samba shares from the Ubuntu Server computer despite being able to previously with out issue. `smbtree` was returning nothing. Interestingly nmap was showing ports 139 and 445 to be open when ran on Ubuntu Server but closed when scanned from another computer? I have tried many things to solve this problem including adding `client max protocol = NT1` under the [global] section in the smb.conf file. I tried replacing the smb.conf file with a copy of the same file that has samba working perfectly on another linux computer. I tried this, I tried that, nothing worked. So in the end I decided to remove and reinstall samba and start again.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge samba samba-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After reinstalling samba it appears it has installed but will not start.

As near as I can tell the problem is this:

```
/usr/sbin/smbd: error while loading shared libraries: libreplace.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

[This post](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=722615) seems to be saying its a bug?

[This post](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+question/292198) seems to be saying I have "installed different and conflicting versions of samba from different sources" but I don't think so. I only ever used apt to install software.

Any true Ubuntu Jedi's out there who can help a wannabe Ubuntu Jedi out?

Thanks heaps :-)

Comment: Your first 'post' is for *experimental* debian only issue solved in 2013 & never affected Ubuntu. Your second assumption is about `apt` which installs using whatever sources you have added to your system, so it does not disqualify your only using `apt`. Given you're confused about 'debian!=ubuntu' I'd firstly check your sources as per your second added post, ie. that you've not added sources from another release, or unofficial source & created the issue.

Comment: Actually the first time I tried to re-install I did `sudo tasksel install samba-server`, would that cause my problem? In any event would uninstalling according to this [https://askubuntu.com/questions/820108/cannot-reinstall-samba-after-deleting-its-config-file-from-etc-samba] post solve the issue of any conflicting version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we talking about missing `libreplace.so.0` library - then it came from `libwbclient0` (see search results on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libreplace.so.0)).

So you need to reinstall the package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwbclient0
```

Comment: N0rbert you are Ubuntu Jedi :-) I actually tried this but it was the --reinstall option that did the trick. Thank you so much, I spent ages on Google trying to find a solution before posting here. smbtree is still producing no output but that's for a separate question.